# Successively down the rows, assign value to a column based on conditions in another columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to populate the column New based on the values in column A and the comparison between columns B and C. I want the column New to have the initial value=1 from the start, and to have memory down the rows, but to reset to 1 at certain conditions.

New is set to 1 as initial value.

Let's look at row 3: Since A=40>30 and B=C, then New=New+1=2, since New=1 in row 2 above.

Let's look at row 6: Since A=40>30 and B<>C, then New=1 (counting starting over).

Creating initial table where New will be manipulated later on:

```
CREATE TABLE table_20220112
(
Ordered_by int,
A   float,
B   nvarchar(100) ,
C   nvarchar(100),
New int,
);
INSERT INTO table_20220112
VALUES
(1,10,'Apples','Apples',0),
(2,5,'Apples','Apples',0),
(3,40,'Apples','Apples',0),
(4,10,'Apples','Apples',0),
(5,50,'Apples','Apples',0),
(6,40,'Oranges','Apples',0),
(7,10,'Oranges','Apples',0),
(8,25,'Oranges','Bananas',0);
select * from table_20220112
--drop table table_20220112
```

Code logic would be something like this (I do not know the corresponding SQL-syntax):

```
New=1 (initail value before going in a looping down all rows)
If A<=30 Then
   IF B=C Then New=New
   Else if B<>C Then New=1
Else If A>30 Then 
   IF B=C Then New=New+1
   Else if B<>C Then New=1
END IF
```

Desired outcome:

| Ordered_by | A | B | C | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | Apples | Apples | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | Apples | Apples | 1 |
| 3 | 40 | Apples | Apples | 2 |
| 4 | 10 | Apples | Apples | 2 |
| 5 | 50 | Apples | Apples | 3 |
| 6 | 40 | Oranges | Apples | 1 |
| 7 | 10 | Oranges | Apples | 1 |
| 8 | 25 | Oranges | Bananas | 1 |

Comment: is there another column that identify the ordering of the rows ?

Comment: Yes, you need to order this table to get the wanted result. So how can we order it, do you have some column we can use to `order by` ?

Comment: Presumably you could do with with `LAG` and a windowed `COUNT` or something; but not without a column to denote the order of your data. Without said column, what you want is impossible.

Comment: This table should be regarded as already ordered! I guess you can always create a new column with row values 1,2,3,4...if you need same ordering...but as I said, this table should be seen as already ordered. It is just about manipulating an existing table, the column New more precisely, you can say.

Comment: *"This table should be regarded as already ordered!"* It can't be, tables are inherently unordered. It's like looking at a table full of pages and pages of text, and saying "it's in order!", but when you pick up the page nearest to you it's page 30, and then the one's adjacent to it are pages 192 and 4. If you don't have a column to order the data on, then (as mentioned) what you want is impossible.

Comment: So, now I have modified the table, now the table is ordered by Ordered_by. I have changed the code creating the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursive cte and implement that logic using `CASE` expression

```
with rcte as
(
    select  Ordered_by, A, B, C, New = 1
    from    #table_20220112
    where   Ordered_by  = 1

    union all

    select  t.Ordered_by, t.A, t.B, t.C, 
            New = case when t.A <= 30 
                       then case when t.B = t.C then r.New else 1 end
                       when t.A >  30 
                       then case when t.B = t.C then r.New + 1 else 1 end
                       end
    from    rcte r
            inner join #table_20220112 t    on  r.Ordered_by    = t.Ordered_by - 1
)
select  *
from    rcte
order by Ordered_by
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this solved my issue!